# Change assert behavior for Debug (SIGABRT -> SIGTRAP)

Tags: c, debugging, signals, assert, abort

I'm trying to debug a program on Debian built with gcc/g++ (`DEBUG=1` and `NDEBUG` undefined). I'm using a third party library and its built for debugging too (`DEBUG=1`, `NDEBUG` undefined, plus other debugging defines). The library is 150K lines and its full of asserts. This is good.

My code has a bug, and I'm trying to debug the SQL query now. Its causing an assert to fire in the third party library. This is OK and its par for the course.

However, that braindead Posix specified behavior is crashing the program when the `assert` fires in the library. That's useless behavior while debugging for a "[debugging and diagnostic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/assert.html)" feature. That's got to be one of the stupidest decisions from that committee, and its no wonder many folks rarely use it during development.

I want to change the behavior such that when the assert fires, it raise a `SIGTRAP` rather than a `SIGABRT`. I'm a little constrained because I did not write the third party library (my code use `MY_ASSERT`, and it calls `SIGTRAP` so I can continue and watch negative code paths).

I'm aware that I can install or change signal handlers via gdb, but gdb already stops on `SIGABRT` before passing it to the program and aborting. I also tried to install a custom `SIGABRT` signal handler, which does not appear to help since the abort still occurs.

How can I change `assert`'s behavior to raise a `SIGTRAP` when debugging?

Answer (score 2):

For linux, you can define an [`__assert_fail`](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---assert-fail-1.html) function that can raise a `SIGTRAP`, rather than the default implementation.

```
void __assert_fail(const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Assert: %s failed at %s:%d in function %s", assertion, file, line, function);
    raise(SIGTRAP);
}
```

The spec says that you're actually supposed to terminate the program at this point, and as the function is declared as having `__attribute__((noreturn))` in `signal.h`.

You can add some iffy code like this (edited to use `ptrace` detection via `fork` rather than signals):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

static int ptrace_failed;

static int
detect_ptrace(void)
{
    int status, waitrc;

    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child == -1) return -1;
    if (child == 0) {
        if (ptrace(PT_ATTACH, getppid(), 0, 0))
            exit(1);
        do {
            waitrc = waitpid(getppid(), &status, 0);
        } while (waitrc == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        ptrace(PT_DETACH, getppid(), (caddr_t)1, SIGCONT);
        exit(0);
    }
    do {
        waitrc = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    } while (waitrc == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void
detect_debugger(void)
{
    ptrace_failed = detect_ptrace();
}

void __assert_fail(const char * assertion, const char * file, unsigned int line, const char * function) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Assert: %s failed at %s:%d in function %s\n", assertion, file, line, function);
    if (ptrace_failed)
        raise(SIGTRAP);
    else
        abort();
}
```

Which triggers `SIGTRAP` when run under gdb, but otherwise triggers `SIGABRT`. I've tested it linked in and via `LD_PRELOAD` and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Patesh, I'll try it soon. I think my other choice is an injection vis `LD_PRELOAD` tricks, which seems a bit extreme to me. What the hell was Posix thinking .....

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work when I tested by implementing `__assert_fail` in my `main` source file. `__assert_fail` was never called.

Comment: Platform? Architecture? Compilation options? the `__assert_fail` function **is** globally visible (if not then it will simply not work)? I tested it with a simple: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { assert(argc != 1); }` as the main method and it worked just fine on an i386/x64 system.

Comment: Note that if you assert with a compile-time constant expression it will change the behaviour (it won't work, you'll get a SEGV on returning from the assertion handler)